# Is it "dressing" if I cooked my "stuffing" outside of the turkey?

Tags: meaning, food

I've always cooked my Thanksgiving stuffing without actually putting it inside the turkey. Does it have to be stuffed into the turkey to be called *stuffing*?

Comment: that's what she.. asked?

Comment: Belongs on cooking? :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The term 'stuffing' is used for the stuff that could go into a turkey, even if it never made it into a turkey.  It might be more accurate to say dressing (but then, are the (sweet) potatoes or the cranberry sauce dressing too - and why one but not the other?), but most people would not bother with that fine a distinction.

Maybe this belongs on the [Cooking](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/)?  Or, maybe you'd get alternative answers there.

Comment: They even sell, or there are recipes for "stove top stuffing" - that is, there is never any expectation that it will go inside anything except the person eating it.

Answer (score 5):

I think the difference between *dressing* and *stuffing* is mostly regional or dialect-related: in some places, if it's made of a starchy substance with flavorings, then it's *stuffing* regardless of whether it ever saw the inside of a bird, while in other places, it's *dressing* even though it was (under)cooked inside the turkey. However, there are certainly people and cookbooks (Joy of Cooking, for example) which make the distinction of stuffing=inside/dressing=outside.

As to why only this one dish type is called dressing, even though the sweet potatoes and cranberries and green beans appear to serve the same purpose, I couldn't tell you. Technically, if we were using *dressing* according to its usual definition (e.g. salad dressing), then the **gravy** should get this appellation.

Comment: Until recently in Canada, it would be dressing regardless. The term "stuffing" was one I never heard except on the very occasional television show originating in the United States that featured a turkey dinner, and it didn't become anything like common until the Stove Top brand made it to the supermarket shelves. These days, there's a distinct generational divide -- the same divide we see between users of "sofa" and "chesterfield" (lower-case in the generic).