# What is the difference between sauce and dressing?

Tags: nouns, food

What is the difference between sauce and dressing? Their purpose seems to be the same.

Comment: [This dictionary](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/dressing) says dressing is a "sauce for food"

Comment: Related: [Is it “dressing” if I cooked my “stuffing” outside of the turkey?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5897/is-it-dressing-if-i-cooked-my-stuffing-outside-of-the-turkey), [Spaghetti and gravy](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2455/spaghetti-and-gravy), [What's the adjective form of “sauce” as “salty” is to “salt”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16451/whats-the-adjective-form-of-sauce-as-salty-is-to-salt)

Comment: I think this is more appropriate for Cooking.SE.

Answer (score 3):

In general, **sauces are cooked** whereas **dressings are uncooked**.

Comment: Turkey dressing is cooked.

Comment: @tchrist - I don't know how your mother made it, but I think most people would agree that turkey dressing is a different kind of dressing than what might be confused with a sauce.  The problem with trying to treat commonly used words as jargon words - which is what OP is doing in his question - is that there are always going to be lots of examples where the jargon is not used consistently by people who don't treat the words as jargon.

Comment: I think that may be an American thing.  To my mind, dressing the turkey results in trimmings, not dressing.  Inconsistent, I know, but language is weird sometimes.  Or do you mean that turkey gravy is called dressing?

Comment: @Christi - I'm inclined to agree.  Gravy isn't the dressing, at least I've never heard the term used that way.  I'm pretty sure that when people say "turkey dressing" they are referring to what I would tend to call "stuffing".

Answer (score 2):

*Dressing* and *sauce* each have several non-overlapping senses in which they differ. The noun *[dressing](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dressing#English)* has meanings "Material applied to a wound for protection or therapy", "Something added to the soil as a fertilizer etc.", a scolding ("dressing down"), and "The activity of getting dressed", as well as "A sauce, especially a cold one for salads."   The noun *[sauce](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sauce)* has meanings like booze ("on the sauce") and impertinence or sauciness ("answered back with sauce") among others, besides "a liquid (often thickened) condiment or accompaniment to food."

While *sauce* almost never refers to *[salad dressings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salad_dressing#Dressings)* (such as *[salad cream](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/salad_cream)*), *dressing* for its part sometimes refers to oil, vinegar, etc. as a sauce or marinade for meats.

Answer (score 1):

Dressing is only used in the context of salad.  It would be incorrect to say that a salad was in a sauce.

Comment: While salads only have dressings, not sauces, many other things have dressings. Thanksgiving turkey, for example, is served with a stuffing or [dressing](https://www.google.com/search?q=turkey+dressing).